# How to use Django imports in a django app without starting the app

Tags: python, django

Let's say my main app structure is like

```
App -
    - __init__.py
    - xyz.py
  API - 
    - __init__.py
    - abc.py
  Custom- 
    - __init__.py
    - s1.py
    - s2.py
```

Normally when running `django` I can do `from API.abc import function` from `s1.py` file. However when I run  `s1` file separately it gives import errors. So how can I make existing imports work.

Comment: Who give you errors IDE or Django ?

Comment: I am in `App` folder.  I tried running from  console  `python Custom/s1.py` since I want to run this file separately.

Comment: Please give me all your trying code and project structure...

Comment: My directroy structure is very big and woudn't be very helpful, actually I can get away with relative imports etc. but would need to change a quite a few places. So wanted if exiting code can run as it is.

Comment: Ok django shell is a best way use the answer of @matyas it good way to work your bug ! Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

If you want to interactively test your django code without running the django app you can do it either through the **django shell**:

```
python manage.py shell
```

this will give you an interactive django shell where you can import and run code just like in any other django view

or write a **custom management command** (useful if you want to run some script related to your django app)
save  the file in `yourproject/yourapp//management/commands/mycommand.py`

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
from polls.models import Question as Poll

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Closes the specified poll for voting'

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument('poll_id', nargs='+', type=int)

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        for poll_id in options['poll_id']:
            try:
                poll = Poll.objects.get(pk=poll_id)
            except Poll.DoesNotExist:
                raise CommandError('Poll "%s" does not exist' % poll_id)

            poll.opened = False
            poll.save()

            self.stdout.write(self.style.SUCCESS('Successfully closed poll "%s"' % poll_id))
```

then you can run your custom management command with
`python manage.py mycommand`
[source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-management-commands/)

if you want to just run an unrelated script make sure to set your PYTHONPATH AND/OR DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE when running the python script:

```
PYTHONPATH=/path/to/project DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=djangoproject.settings python s1.py
```

Comment: I don't want to run `django` at all, think just like there is a directory structure like `django` with nothing to do with it's functions of functionality, now how do I run a script which is in this directory structure.

Comment: PYTHONPATH=/path/to/project DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=djangoproject.settings python s1.py

Comment: would I be able to access django settings just settings `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` how will a file know to look for this variable.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by adding `App` path to system path where python looks for imports.

```
import os
import sys
path = os.getcwd()
sys.path.append(path)
```

Now existing import as per Django directory structure work without any change.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of you running these `s1.py` or `s2.py` as individual files, try to run the methods from those files from your home directory of Django project using `python manage.py shell`